# vim-latex: add new math environment

Tags: vim-latex

I am using vim latex-suite for writing, and I make extensive use of the `tikzcd`-environment for typesetting commutative diagrams. However, vim-latex does not recognize this as a math environment and e.g. highlights every caret sign as a syntax error.

Is there any way to tell vim-latex that `tikzcd` enters math mode?

Comment: I'm not sure that `vim-latex` redefines the standard tex syntax definitions for vim.  Assuming it doesn't you want to customize the TeX syntax definitions in `$VIMRUNTIME/syntax/tex.vim`.  You might perhaps contact the maintainer to ask him to think about adding something for you.  http://www.drchip.org/astronaut/vim/index.html#SYNTAX_TEX

Comment: otherwise see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/412862/vim-does-not-recognize-math-environment-but-handles-other-math-fine?noredirect=1#412867