# Vim does not recognize math environment (but handles other math fine)

Tags: math-mode, editors, vim, syntax-highlighting

So on one of my pc's the vim install dos not recognize math environments such as `align` and `equation`

Is there a way to turn this on?

Comment: Despite my answer below, this is a question about vim's syntax highlighting and not about TeX, imho, so best is asked elsewhere.

Comment: First; Thanks for the answer @Skillmon. I can see where you are comming from, but I there has been questions like this one before (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/347878/vim-latex-add-new-math-environment) and i feel i tagged nicely. Just wiered that vim-latex didn't catch it for me.

Comment: vim-latexsuite is not there for syntax highlighting, but to give you convenience short cuts to edit tex files faster.

Comment: I thought it did a bit of both worlds, Good to know XD

Comment: This may be true, I'm not completely sure. But the original idea is to separate syntax highlighting from other ex commands (you could put any ex commands in a syntax highlighting file).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check if the syntax highlighting rules are up to date. Those should be located under `/usr/share/vim/vim80/syntax/tex.vim`. In this file there should be a block name `Standard Math Zones:`. Below that you'll find some lines stating something like:

```
call TexNewMathZone("A","displaymath",1)
```

To this block add the environments you find missing. E.g., for `align` use:

```
call TexNewMathZone("E","align",1)
```

If there is no starred form of the environment you want to add, use

```
call TexNewMathZone(suffix,name,0)
```

instead.

But perhaps you shouldn't make those changes system wide but on a per user basis. So create a copy of the file in `/usr/share/...` paste it in a folder in $HOME where vim finds it and make those changes there.

If the syntax highlighting is correct on the other machines, maybe copy the files from there to your machine where it fails to highlight correctly.

The default folder for the per-user-basis syntax highlighting would be something like `~/.vim/syntax/`. If it doesn't exist, create it and everything should work.

**EDIT:** Perhaps a better approach is to create a short custom syntax file which sources the system wide one in the beginning and add some stuff there. The setup would then be the following file `~/.vim/syntax/tex.vim`:

```
so $VIMRUNTIME/syntax/tex.vim

" adapt to match your system wide variable in $VIMRUNTIME/syntax/tex.vim
let s:tex_fast= "bcmMprsSvV"

if !exists("g:tex_no_math")
 call TexNewMathZone("E","align",1)
endif

if s:tex_fast =~# 'r'
  syn region texRefZone     matchgroup=texStatement start="\\autoref{"  end="}\|%stopzone\>"    contains=@texRefGroup
endif
```

In the above I've also added `\autoref` to the list of known commands for referencing stuff as an example.

I think this should be a better approach since you get bugfixes and new features from updates in your system wide file this way.

Alternatively (but with the same effects) put the file in `~/.vim/after/syntax/` and remove the first line (that's what is suggested in `:help latex-syntax`).

Comment: This does not seem to work (I went with copying the file in my home folder)

Comment: @ThorbjørnE.K.Christensen not directly in home. But in your $HOME there should be a folder containing vim configuration stuff on a per user basis. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: @ThorbjørnE.K.Christensen you're welcome. In fact, I was too lazy all the time to fix this on my local machine, too, and now that you've asked I did fix it :)

Comment: Then we both got something from this, how nice ;-)

Comment: @ThorbjørnE.K.Christensen see my edit...

Comment: That's really cool @Skillmon, Will this also work if 'E' is not the correct letter? i.e. if the tex.vim file ends with 'R' or 'A' ?

Comment: @ThorbjørnE.K.Christensen I hope I understand your comment correctly. The "E" you provide is a suffix -- and that's about it what I understood from taking a quick look at the definition of `TexNewMathZone`. It is used for some definitions. Perhaps it's best to just use a new one for each environment.

Comment: Okay, it was just in my original file they used a new one for every environment, so I unrightly assumed that it would not work otherwise.

Comment: @ThorbjørnE.K.Christensen I don't know, if it does work otherwise or not. You might just test it.

Answer (score 3):

For some reason, the `amsmath` environments were recently [removed](https://github.com/vim/vim/commit/f0b03c4e98f8a7184d8b4a5d702cbcd602426923#diff-9aa7419d9504f85f995d943175f49e46) from vim's syntax files and split into a [separate package](http://www.drchip.org/astronaut/vim/index.html#LATEXPKGS). After downloading that package decompress it and run

```
$ vim amsmath.vba
:so %
```

to re-enable `amsmath` support.